# Currency is not defined

Tags: discord, discord.js

I decided to use this [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/sequelize/currency.html#file-overview)  to create my economy discord bot. Apparently something went wrong as I was about to run the bot. It had this error message and it said :

```
Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'add', {
                       ^

ReferenceError: currency is not defined
```

I have no idea what was wrong with it. Here's my index.js:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();

Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'add', {
    /* eslint-disable-next-line func-name-matching */
    value: async function add(id, amount) {
        const user = currency.get(id);
        if (user) {
            user.balance += Number(amount);
            return user.save();
        }
        const newUser = await Users.create({ user_id: id, balance: amount });
        currency.set(id, newUser);
        return newUser;
    },
});

Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'getBalance', {
    /* eslint-disable-next-line func-name-matching */
    value: function getBalance(id) {
        const user = currency.get(id);
        return user ? user.balance : 0;
    },
});

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

});

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    currency.add(message.author.id, 1);

    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    const input = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim();
    if (!input.length) return;
    const [, command, commandArgs] = input.match(/(\w+)\s*([\s\S]*)/);

    if (command === 'balance') {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        return message.channel.send(`${target.tag} has ${currency.getBalance(target.id)}`);
    } else if (command === 'inventory') {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        const user = await Users.findOne({ where: { user_id: target.id } });
        const items = await user.getItems();

        if (!items.length) return message.channel.send(`${target.tag} has nothing!`);
        return message.channel.send(`${target.tag} currently has ${items.map(t => `${t.amount} ${t.item.name}`).join(', ')}`);
    } else if (command === 'transfer') {
        const currentAmount = currency.getBalance(message.author.id);
        const transferAmount = commandArgs.split(/ +/).find(arg => !/<@!?\d+>/.test(arg));
        const transferTarget = message.mentions.users.first();

        if (!transferAmount || isNaN(transferAmount)) return message.channel.send(`Sorry ${message.author}, that's an invalid amount`);
        if (transferAmount > currentAmount) return message.channel.send(`Sorry ${message.author} you don't have that much.`);
        if (transferAmount <= 0) return message.channel.send(`Please enter an amount greater than zero, ${message.author}`);

        currency.add(message.author.id, -transferAmount);
        currency.add(transferTarget.id, transferAmount);

        return message.channel.send(`Successfully transferred ${transferAmount} to ${transferTarget.tag}. Your current balance is ${currency.getBalance(message.author.id)}`);
    } else if (command === 'buy') {
        const item = await CurrencyShop.findOne({ where: { name: { [Op.like]: commandArgs } } });
        if (!item) return message.channel.send('That item doesn\'t exist.');
        if (item.cost > currency.getBalance(message.author.id)) {
            return message.channel.send(`You don't have enough currency, ${message.author}`);
        }

        const user = await Users.findOne({ where: { user_id: message.author.id } });
        currency.add(message.author.id, -item.cost);
        await user.addItem(item);

        message.channel.send(`You've bought a ${item.name}`);
    } else if (command === 'shop') {
        const items = await CurrencyShop.findAll();
        return message.channel.send(items.map(i => `${i.name}: ${i.cost}`).join('\n'), { code: true });
    } else if (command === 'leaderboard') {
        return message.channel.send(
            currency.sort((a, b) => b.balance - a.balance)
                .filter(user => client.users.cache.has(user.user_id))
                .first(10)
                .map((user, position) => `(${position + 1}) ${(client.users.cache.get(user.user_id).tag)}: ${user.balance}`)
                .join('\n'),
            { code: true }
        );
    }
});

client.login(`[TOKEN]`);
```

I presume the only probelm of this code is Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'add', { as it can't define what is currency. I hope someone can help...

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to use the `currency` variable but you haven't defined it so JavaScript is rightfully complaining because it doesn't know what `currency` is.

The following line from the guide is missing from your code:

```js
const currency = new Discord.Collection();
```

Answer (score 0):

## You have to define currency.

Basic js-